# 401 Unauthorized Error with Web Service

Tags: .net, security, iis, web-services, http-status-code-401

I must be missing something very basic. Here is the scenario

We have a ASP.NET 2.0 WebService (Server 2003) with the following settings:

- SSL
- Integrated Security
- Anom. Access DISABLED
- Running under NETWORK SERVICE
- Exposed (i.e. can access from public
  internet)
- Service returns data from database
  using application username/password,
  does NOT call another webservice
- No impersonation is set on the
  service although I have tried to
  toggle that as well.

We have a client machine (same domain) that is disconnected from the LAN but is using an air card. The user is signed into the laptop using their AD username/password/domain.

In the code at the proxy level, we have `service.PreAuthenticate` = true
We have also trid using both `DefaultCredentials` and `DefaultNetworkCredentials` with the same result.

1. .NET windows client works WITH VPN
2. .NET windows client gets a 401:
   Unauthorized WITHOUT VPN (Note:  no
   inner exception is returned)
3. IE works with or without VPN.

My assumption (maybe incorrect) was that if I passed in the DefaultNetworkCredentials to the proxy class, that it would pass in the domain credentials to authenticate.  IE is obviously doing some magic to make this work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Any proxy settings in the configuration of the client ?

Answer (score 0):

IE uses NTLM by default if your using Firefox, Safari etc.. you'll have to specify the domains server.

This happened to me a while back with a Web App.

http://www.nateirwin.net/2007/01/19/enabling-ntlm-authentication-in-firefox-and-internet-explorer/

Comment: I got confused since you mentioned IE.